# Would it be considered good to communicate with interviewer before interview?

Tags: interviewing, job-offer

I have got an interview offer from a multi-national company. Somehow I got to learn that I know the person who is going to interview me there. I mean he is not my close friend as such, but I have interacted with him couple of or quite a few times in the past. And I am very sure he is also aware that he knows me.

Question: Is it good to communicate with interviewer (on Linked-In or on Facebook etc) before interview just to build good repo? Would they take it positively?

Comment: I don't think it would be smart to contact the interviewer. They could _recuse_ themselves from interviewing with you.

Answer (score 8):

I don’t think it would make much difference one way or the other. If you decide to do it, I’d keep it short. Something like:

> I heard I’ll be interviewing with you next week. Look forward to seeing you again and learning more about the company!

Answer (score 7):

> Would they take it positively?

This all *depends* on the individual, but based on my experience I would not recommend this. It makes you appear over eager, and perhaps even a bit desperate.

The *standard procedure* is to wait for the interview first, and **if** it goes well then *perhaps* you reach out via linkedIn or the like.

Furthermore, I would urge you to **not to reach out via FaceBook** as that is reservered typically for more personal (*actual friends*) networking where linkedIn is for professional networking.

Answer (score 3):

**No, don’t send uninvited communications to your interviewer before the interview.**

**You may also want to let your recruiter know that you’re aquatinted with your expected interviewer** - your existing relationship may be a reason to find a new interviewer.

Many organizations have developed healthy and strong recruiting processes designed to limit bias and favoritism - frequent among these is a policy of *zero-introduction interviewing*. That is, the interview is the first time an interviewer and interviewee meet. This ensures that past encounters outside of the context and control of interviewing don’t bias the interviewer’s decisions and ratings.

Best of luck with the interview and potential new opporutnity!